# Stoneborn Pact on ranged characters

Tags: league-of-legends

When **Stoneborn Pact** is activated, the user and other allies heal for *5% + 2.5% Max Health* over 2 seconds, during 4 seconds.

It also notes that the effect is **halved** for ranged characters.

What exactly is halved?

- Is the healing is halved?
- Does it heal over a longer period of time (Hp/second is halved)?
- Does the mark last less time?
- A combination of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Stoneborn_Pact)-

> Your crowd control effects brand enemy champions with an Earthen Rune for 4 seconds. Other allied champions who attack branded enemies heal for 5 (+ 2.5% of your maximum health) over 2 seconds (halved to 2.5 (+ 1.25% of your maximum health) if you are ranged).

So the healing is halved for ranged champs.

Also note:

> - Earthen Rune can be applied by any source of crowd control and has no    internal cooldown.
> - 「40% of the amount is healed 」 on-hit and 「 60% 」 over 2 seconds. The    on-hit component stacks and the heal over time's duration
>     refreshes    on-hit.